# Java socket Chat application

Tags: java, serversocket

Hi I am looking for guidance in to building a chat application using socket, which allows clients to create rooms for other clients to join in and chat. I have build a chat application which works and clients can join in however clients are in one room and can not move around to other rooms. I have created a similar application with multiply rooms using rmi user can add rooms for other clients to join and chat. This time i want to practice using socket. Any sort of help or guidance to get me started would be great thank you.

Comment: We will not get you started, that is not the purpose of this site (search through the questions and use google for that). But if you do have an issue, we will help resolve it.

Comment: Sorry. I am not asking for codes. I think i need to re-write what i meant. I have created a multi-chat application that accepts multiply clients, but I want to no how the server can allow clients to create rooms. Right now all my socket chat application just adds any clients to the server ArrayList and updates all clients when a message comes through. I  think my question would be, how would the server no if the client wants to create or join a room?

Comment: Define and implement your own protocol for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can work out, you want to

- connect via plain IO Sockets and perhaps blocking NIO with one reader thread per socket.

  - I suggest you have a handler class which wraps each socket.
- use a text based protocol.

  - you need a command to add to a room, to remove froma room, to get a list of current rooms, and to send a message.
- allow a single client to subscribe/listen/appear in multiple rooms at once

  - this means you need a set of handlers in each room.
- you want to handle slow consumers and disconnects gracefully.

Comment: 1st point: I am not too sure what you mean sorry, but it sounds right to me.

2nd point: I was thinking about that but couldnt figure out how i could do it. Which i'll try and play around with that now.

3rd point: yeah that is correct.

4th point: that is what i want to do correct :).

5th: I understand what mean.

Comment: I don't know what you don't know. ;) Ask me a further question if you like.

Comment: sorry i press enter too early

Answer (score 0):

To implement the communication layeryou should take a look into [netty](http://netty.io) or [apache mina](http://mina.apache.org). Both address your needs for the client and server side. I guess they already have a chat protocol sample.

Comment: Thanks i'll be read up on that, but i was just thinking on using just sockets and server sockets. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Both frameworks uses nio-sockets and provide an abstration of the low-level stuff so one can focus on the protocol.